# Sending message through other apps

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to send msg body and contacts from my app to other available sms apps like whatsapp, default sms app, skype etc. But it is working properly for only default app and for others it is either taking only msg body or only contacts...I have tried other Actions like SEND also..

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + destination);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,uri);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editMessage.getText().toString());
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
data.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            data.setData(Uri.parse("sms:(234) 567-8901"));
            data.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello from "+getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
```

It works for me.

Comment: thanks.i tried this..but this is also working only for native sms app...not with other apps..

Comment: Sry for the late reply. Well i have another sms sending app named **Free SMS India** and when i click the **sms** buttons it is shown too.